# How to sign in to iCloud without verification code sent to other device?

Tags: macos, icloud

I just formatted my Macbook Pro and reinstalled MacOS. When I try to sign in to iCloud, I am getting this message: "Enter the verification code sent to your other devices.". I don't however have any other Apple devices, which makes it impossible for me to sign in. Is there an alternative way to sign in (e.g. getting verification code by SMS)?

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround using SMS. In a web browser, sign in to the Apple Store and when it asks for a verification code, click the "I didn't receive a verification code" link. Select to receive the code by SMS. Now, instead of using the code you receive by SMS to sign in on the Apple Store, you can use it to sign in on your Macbook.

Comment: This does work (yes even in 2020), but why in sweet baby Jesus's name does this work, isn't the whole point of 2FA authentication the CORRELATION between the *request* and the code?